# newSetFromMap use of Boolean

Tags: java, collections

The [Collections.newSetFromMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)) method has the following signature:

```
public static <E> Set<E> newSetFromMap​(Map<E,​Boolean> map)
```

What is the significance of the Boolean parameter for the map? Is it something that I need to be concerned with if I am only interested in the `E` parameter type?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_newsetfrommap.htm

Comment: @YCF_L thanks. So from the example, it seems the Boolean parameter to Map is completely ignored? If that was the case, shouldn't it have been `Void`?

Comment: @k314159 then consider the following two methods and their return value:
`public boolean remove(Object o)   { return m.remove(o) != null; }` & `public boolean add(E e) { return m.put(e, Boolean.TRUE) == null; }`. Both taken from the decompiled `Collections.class`, Java 1.8.0_251.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `newSetFromMap` works is it uses the provided Map, and puts a dummy value in it on `add`. All other operations simply operate on the keySet of the map. It happens to use Boolean.TRUE as the dummy value (see the [source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/289ae798f4c95676e8d97640c62f2d1611ce306f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L5654)), so the input type `Map<E, Boolean>` is required for this to be type-safe.

The restrictive type also helps encourage proper usage, per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)):

> The specified map must be empty at the time this method is invoked,
> and should not be accessed directly after this method returns. These
> conditions are ensured if the map is created empty, passed directly to
> this method, and no reference to the map is retained, as illustrated
> in the following code fragment:
>
> ```
> Set<Object> weakHashSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
>     new WeakHashMap<Object, Boolean>());
> ```

If the method accepted a `Map<E, Object>` as it theoretically could, it would be easy to pass in an existing map that already contains non-boolean values, which is discouraged and could result in surprising behaviour.

So no, it's nothing to be concerned about so long as you are using the method correctly as specified in the docs.

Comment: Also, with the use of the diamond operator, implementer has be concerned about that even less... `Set<E> weakHashSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<>());`

Comment: @dbl but mind that despite the diamond operator was introduced in Java 7, it took until Java 8 for the type inference to work with that code example. The original example was from Java 6…